# virtual column in Oracle database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have 5 columns in table. I have to store `difference of max value and min value` in another `column`. I am using below query. here `a b c d e` are column names.

```
ALTER TABLE samples ADD
(Range_value NUMBER(10,2) GENERATED ALWAYS
 AS (max(a,b,c,d,e)-Min(a,b,c,d,e)) VIRTUAL);
```

I am getting below error.

```
Error starting at line : 28 in command -
ALTER TABLE samples ADD
(Range_value NUMBER(10,2) GENERATED ALWAYS
 AS (max(a,b,c,d,e)-Min(a,b,c,d,e)) VIRTUAL)
Error report -
ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
00934. 00000 -  "group function is not allowed here"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

If group function are not allowed, is there anyway to resolve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use GREATEST and LEAST

```
ALTER TABLE samples ADD
(Range_value NUMBER(10,2) GENERATED ALWAYS
 AS (GREATEST (a,b,c,d,e)-LEAST(a,b,c,d,e)) VIRTUAL);
```

*see: db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f60dbf03092cd80b884499706590d4ee)*

These functions work with the current row, and can be used for your virtual column, whereas MIN/MAX operate across multiple rows and cannot be used in your virtual column.

If you do really need to operate across multiple rows then a view may be the simplest alternative.

Comment: That's a good explanation and, yes, `GREATEST` and `LEAST` seem to be what Shruti is looking for. Only thing one must bear in mind is that they result in NULL when one or more values are NULL.

Comment: Thank you Used_By_already .  thank you @Thorsten for highlighting an important point